# Hide <li> tag when clicked with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing some exercises to practice my JQuery but i can't manage to find the solution with this. I just want to hide the first element of the list when it's clicked.

I've tried this:

JS

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("li.oculta").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
     });
    });
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
 p{
  background-color: #AA55AA;
 }
 </style>
 <script src="/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <ul class='list1'>
  <li class="oculta">Taco</li>
  <li>Jamón</li>
  <li>Queso</li>
 </ul>
 <ul class='list2'>
  <li class="oculta">Coke</li>
  <li>Leche</li>
  <li>Té</li>
 </ul>
 </body>
 </html>
```

But i can't figure out why isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: your url to `jquery`  is wrong

Comment: @itsgoingdown Thank yoy so much, i was getting out of my nerves with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple error, the code is all right, but you forgot to import jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("li.oculta:first-of-type").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
 p{
  background-color: #AA55AA;
 }
 </style>
 <script src="/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <ul class='list1'>
  <li class="oculta">Taco</li>
  <li>Jamón</li>
  <li>Queso</li>
 </ul>
 <ul class='list2'>
  <li class="oculta">Coke</li>
  <li>Leche</li>
  <li>Té</li>
 </ul>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I was getting out of my nerves with this, thank you! It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use `on('click',function(){...` instead of `.click(function(){...`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.oculta").on('click',function(){
      $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vwzgf2t/)